# How to do inner join with JDO 1.0

Tags: jdo, jdoql

I am working on Healthcare Project which is developed using JDO 1.0. I have googled and i have not found good stuff for JDO 1.0. My problem is that, I have to join two tables Encounter table and History table.The encounter table contains a column which is a foreign key to Historyparent table and History table also contains column which is foreign key to HistoryParent table.Now coming on to  domain structure, Encounter domain is extending HistoryParent domain where as History domain contains field with one-one mapping to HistoryParent domain.Now how to filter encounters with History field data.Thanks for your valuable answers in advance.

Comment: JDO 1.1 ? JDO has specs for v1.0, 2.0, 2.1, 2.2, 3.0 and 3.1

Comment: @DataNucleus please give me the solution

Comment: suggest you look in the docs of your JDO 1.0 provider (whatever it is - you don't seem to mention it). That version of JDO is so ancient now (2003)

Comment: @DataNucleus can you please help me in joining a domain which is extending another domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://download.oracle.com/otndocs/jcp/7734-jdo-1.0.1-mr-spec-oth-JSpec/

I hope this is the Spec you are looking for.